# A Bootstrap-based component: show explaining content, but closed when page loaded

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking for a Bootstrap 3 based solution.

I am writing a web application. On some pages, I need to insert a paragraph of explaining content to help users.

I am hoping to have a Bootstrap-based component that makes the paragraph closed at page load, but gives a visual clue. When clicked it opens the whole paragraph. It can be closed again. The paragraph provides page-wise explanation, not for a field. I don't want any popup or tooltip solution.

I looked through the components coming with Bootstrap 3 and failed to find one just for this.

Any pointer and suggestion is really appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options you have are:

1. [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)
2. [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
3. [Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)
4. [Colapses (or accordions as named in jquery ui)](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

you can too try [Helper Classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) clases like this example:

```
<p class="hidden">your content</p>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I used Colpases, which is directly from Bootstrap.

Comment: All those I mention are from bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which should get you pretty close:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-accordion.php

The effect you're looking for is commonly referred to as an `accordian`.  So if you don't like the example I've given here just google around for `bootstrap accordian` and I'm sure you'll find something to meet your needs.

Comment: I used Colpases, which is directly from Bootstrap.